# tkinter not rendering label size from docker container

Tags: docker, user-interface, tkinter, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the following simple file to create a tkinter gui:

```
# importing tkinter module and Widgets
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Label


# Creating App class which will contain
# Label Widgets
class App:
    def __init__(self, master) -> None:

        # Instantiating master i.e toplevel Widget
        self.master = master

        # Creating first Label i.e with default font-size
        Label(self.master, text="I have default font-size").pack(pady=20)

        # Creating second label
        # This label has a font-family of Arial
        # and font-size of 25
        Label(self.master,
            text="I have a font-size of 25",

            # Changing font-size here
            font=("Arial", 25)
            ).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Instantiating top level
    root = Tk()

    # Setting the title of the window
    root.title("Change font-size of Label")

    # Setting the geometry i.e Dimensions
    root.geometry("400x250")

    # Calling our App
    app = App(root)

    # Mainloop which will cause this toplevel
    # to run infinitely
    root.mainloop()
```

When I run from wsl, I get the correct window:
[image]

When instead I run from the docker container, I get:
[image]

As you can see when running from the docker container I am unable to change the fontsizes.
Does anyone have any ideas. In my dockerfile I have the following lines:

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:2.0.1-cuda11.7-cudnn8-devel

# Copy the YAML file containing additional packages
COPY environment.yml .


RUN mkdir -m a=rw ./data

# Set the noninteractive environment variable
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# install tkinter
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    tk \
    libx11-dev \
    libxext-dev \
    libxss-dev \
    libxft-dev \
    libx11-xcb-dev

# allow screen sharing
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y xorg
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y xfonts-base


# jupyter
RUN pip install jupyter

# Add Tini. Tini operates as a process subreaper for jupyter. This prevents
# kernel crashes.
ENV TINI_VERSION v0.6.0

ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /usr/bin/tini

RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/tini


RUN pip install --upgrade jupyter_http_over_ws>=0.0.7
# build folders
RUN mkdir /workspace/mlflow
RUN mkdir /workspace/tensorboard

#logger variables
ENV MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=file:///workspace/mlflow
ENV TENSORBOARD_LOG_DIR=/workspace/tensorboard


EXPOSE 8888
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 6006

# Create a Conda environment named "EM+" and clone from the base environment
RUN conda create --name EM+ --clone base

# Activate the "EM+" environment
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "EM+", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Update the "EM+" environment with packages from environment.yml
RUN conda env update --file environment.yml --prune


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor

RUN apt-get install -y graphviz


# Set the default command to launch Jupyter Notebook
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "--"]

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

And my docker-compose file is:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  pytorch-notebook:
    build: .
    image: my_image:latest
    container_name: pytorch_notebook
    ports: 
      - 8888:8888
      - 5000:5000
      - 6006:6006
    volumes: 
      - "$PWD:/workspace"
      - "$EXTERNAL_STORAGE:/ext_data"
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix

    restart: always
    environment:
      - GRANT_SUDO=yes
      - JUPYTER_TOKEN=letmein
      - DISPLAY=*******:0


    user: root
    privileged: true
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

Please let me know if you need other information.
Thanks

I have tried restarting the Xming server. I have tried to see if it has something to do with the backend version that tinker is using. Now I am out of ideas